# window.innerWidth<=480 do not work

Tags: jquery

I have a little script that works fine on the pc screen, but when i se it on the phone i dosent work.
I try ed to find answer in here but i coudent find some that is smal as this.
I have use's it before width different stylesheet and there is no problem her.
now i am trying to use it width @media all and(xxxxx) in the same stylesheet and here it docent work on a phone.

```
if(window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth<=480){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.nav').addClass('hide');
      $('header').append('<div class="left_buttom"     onclick="toggleMenu()"><img src="images/nav.png"></div>');  
    });
      function toggleMenu(){
        $('ul.nav').toggleClass('hide');
        $('header .left_buttom').toggleClass('pressed'); //indbygget jq class
      }
}
```

Comment: You should consider to use `window.matchMedia()` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 480) {
        $('ul.nav').addClass('hide');
        $('header').append('<div class="left_buttom" onclick="toggleMenu()"><img src="images/nav.png"></div>');
    }
});

function toggleMenu() {
    $('ul.nav').toggleClass('hide');
    $('header .left_buttom').toggleClass('pressed'); //indbygget jq class
}
```

1. Don 't need `ready` inside `if`
2. No need of `toggleMenu` inside `if`

Comment: that works tanks a lot, the only problem i got now is that the menu that should be hidded on screnne ontel i pussed the bottom, is not hided.

Comment: You can se it on this page http://itopgaver.dk/hanne i am only testing for a client so text and images is morkups.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding meta tag between `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I got this line on my html so that was not the problem, but the answer from Tushar help t but thanks